# Why graphical models from GRASS 7.6 don't work in GRASS 7.8?

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.6, grass-7.8

I was working in some graphical model with grass and developed in GRASS GIS 7.6. Now I did an update with osgeo instaler from GRASS 7.6 to GRASS 7.8. When I try to run a graphical modeler nothing happen, It does not work.

Do I have to make my models again?

Does he graphical modeler from GRASS 7.6 work in GRASS 7.8?

I work in Windows 10.

This is the error I had.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line
1021, in parse_template

this = chr(ESCAPES[this][1])
KeyError
:
'\\E'
During handling of the above exception, another exception
occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gmodeler
\frame.py", line 621, in OnRunModel

self.model.Run(self._gconsole, self.OnModelDone,
parent=self)
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gmodeler
\model.py", line 689, in Run

self.RunAction(item, params, log)
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gmodeler
\model.py", line 596, in RunAction

log.RunCmd(command=item.GetLog(string=False,
substitute=params),
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass78\gui\wxpython\gmodeler
\model.py", line 1211, in GetLog

cmd[idx] = pattern.sub(value, cmd[idx])
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\re.py", line 309, in
_subx

template = _compile_repl(template, pattern)
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\re.py", line 300, in
_compile_repl

return sre_parse.parse_template(repl, pattern)
File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\sre_parse.py", line
1024, in parse_template

raise s.error('bad escape %s' % this, len(this))
re
.
error
:
bad escape \E at position 2
```

Comment: Please edit and add the error message, thanks

Comment: Thanks. I added the error I get in the console. I think that it's an error in Windows only, because I tried in GNU/Linux, ubuntu 19.04, and it works fine.

Comment: OK, now we have to know precisely the winGRASS version - is it 7.8.2?

Comment: Hi markusN, The WinGRASS version is 7.8.2 and was installed with the OSGeo4W Network Installer (64bit)

Comment: Can you make the model (personally) available ?

Comment: Sure! I can share the model and some data to run it. Can you give me some email?

Comment: You can use my OSGeo email from here: https://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Markus_Neteler - the best would be to open a ticket (I can do that for you) in the case that you can make that available via a sharable link (since some other GRASS GIS developer might need to look into this.

Comment: Hi @ManuelAlejandro: Did you solve it together with Markus, or is it still an issue?